# Filter/Search AND select List

Tags: javascript

**The Requirement** is to complete the `script`  to be able to Filter/Search AND select the categories of list items.
The selection must have the priority and clear all the search input.

Here is my CODE:

```
    <script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i; 
    input = document.getElementById('myInput'); 
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase(); 
    ul = document.querySelectorAll(".myUL"); 
    for(j=0;j< ul.length;j++){ 

        li = ul[j].getElementsByTagName("LI"); 
        show = false; 
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) { 
            if (li[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0) { 
                li[i].style.display = "";
                show = true;
            } else { 
                li[i].style.display = "none"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
</script>

    <h1>search</h1>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Search for keywords">

<p>
    <h1>select</h1>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction()">Hefner</a>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction()">Syring</a>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction()">Mccarthy</a>
</p>

    <h1>results</h1>
<ul class="myUL">
<li>Lavonne Hefner</li>
<li>Lavonne Syring</li>
<li>Marcell Syring</li>
<li>Marcell Hefner</li>
<li>Iona Mccarthy</li>
<li>Iona Hefner</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a parameter:

```
<a href="" onclick="changeFilter('Hefner')">Hefner</a>
```

Then add the corresponding function:

```
 function changeFilter(value){
  myInput.value = value; // set filter
  myFunction(); //update results
}
```

Comment: could you please provide a example?

Comment: I am terribly sorry, but I can't make it work.. [jsfiddle.net/9svy1bnb](http://jsfiddle.net/9svy1bnb/)

Comment: @iolli okay, im sorry about that. You might change *myInput* to *document.getElementById("myInput")* ( officially it should work but many browsers dont support it :/)